# jquery not picking up @Model value on button submit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I have a form in which I am posting data using ajax using jQuery. The problem is, when I alert `@Model.Id` or when I try to pass the value in FormData in the view, I can't see the alert and when I keep the breakpoint in the Controller, I get the breakpoint fine upon clicking the Post Comment button. I also get all values on the form except for the Id.

(See the document ready function, there I can access the Id fine. Only when I click the Post Comment button, I have the problem with the Id.)

Here is my view:

```
@model KGSBlog.Models.BlogData

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html>
<body>
 <form id="formPostComment" method="post" asp-controller="BlogData" asp-action="PostComment">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name *" name="name" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email *" name="email" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message *" id="message" cols="45" rows="10" required></textarea>

                                <button type="submit" id="btnPostComment"  class="btn btn-main m-bottom-40">Post Comment</button>

                            </form>

 <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            LoadPartialView(@Model.Id); //Here I can access the Id fine.
            $('#formPostComment').validate({ 
                rules: {
                    name: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 4
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    message: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 10
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            $("#btnPostComment").click(function () {
                alert(@Model.Id); // I cannot see this alert.
                var url = $("#formPostComment").attr("action");
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("Name", $("#name").val());
                formData.append("Email", $("#email").val());
                formData.append("Comment", $("#message").val());
                formData.append("BlogId", @Model.Id); //This value is always 0.
                
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        LoadPartialView(response.blogId);
                        $('#formPostComment')[0].reset();
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

            function LoadPartialView(blogId) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/BlogData/UpdateCommentsPartial",
                    data: { "blogId": blogId },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#haveToReloaddiv").html(data);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                })
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I hit the Post Comment button I see the break point in the Controller action method with all the values of the form, but the Id is always 0.

Comment: Do you see the id in the page source?  The id gets rendered into the js at the time the view is constructed.

Comment: View the *rendered* HTML - not the cshtml.

Comment: *"I can't see the alert"* - do you mean there is no alert?  Or that the alert is blank? If there's no alert, then it means that code is not running and you're getting a form POST rather than the ajax post.  What *exactly* does LoadPartialView do?  The name implies it loads the HTML for the partial view - does that include the `btnPostComment`.

Comment: Most likely your `btnPostComment` doesn't exist when you try to add the click handler.   doc.ready runs when the document is ready - not after some additional ajax runs and adds HTML to the page - putting two doc.readys makes no difference here.  Just before `$("#btnPostComment").click` add `console.log($("#btnPostComment").length` - if this is zero (please confirm) then use event delegation: `$(document).on("click", "#btnPostComment", function...`

Comment: Wow ok I figured out the problem. The problem seems to be for some reason on the form when I say asp-controller="BlogData" asp-action="PostComment". It is posting the data and not the ajax post. Like your SECOND comment. Thank you. So I removed that asp-controller and asp-action and in the Jquery modified the URL like, var url = "/BlogData/PostComment"; and it works.